# How to use image placeholders for preview with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose

With XML, we had the option to use `tools:` for designing by using placeholders when real data is not available. Do we have something similar in Jetpack Compose?

I know I can pass sample data to my composable in a dedicated preview function. But for instance, when an image  source is a URL (that loads by Coil, Glide.. ), even if I pass a sample URL, it can't be loaded in preview. A practical solution for that could save development time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just as an update on cd1 Answer:

`rememberCoilPainter is renamed to rememberImagePainter and its arguments changed`

More info about the changes:

- **rememberCoilPainter** is renamed to **rememberImagePainter** and its
  arguments changed:
- **shouldRefetchOnSizeChange** is replaced with **onExecute**, which has more
  control over if image requests are executed or skipped.
- **requestBuilder** is renamed to **builder**.
- **fadeIn** and **fadeInDurationMs** are removed. Migrate to
  **ImageRequest.Builder.crossfade**.
- **previewPlaceholder** is removed. **ImageRequest.placeholder** is now
  automatically used if inspection mode is enabled.
- **LoadPainter** is renamed to **ImagePainter**.
- **ImagePainter** no longer falls back to executing an image request with
  the root view's size if onDraw is not called. This is most likely to
  be noticeable if you use ImagePainter in a LazyColumn and the Image's
  size isn't constrained. Loader and rememberLoadPainter are removed.
- **LocalImageLoader.current** is not-null and returns the singleton
  ImageLoader by default.
- **DrawablePainter** and **rememberDrawablePainter** are now private.

source: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/

Regarding placeholder visible in preview, the code is:

```kotlin
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
        builder = {
            placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = "some description",
)
```

Answer (score 20):

### 2022 November update

If you are using Coil...

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2")
```

... now you can preview with a placeholder in debug mode only this way:

```
AsyncImage(
   model = "https://www.example.com/image.jpg",
   placeholder = debugPlaceholder(R.drawable.debugPlaceholder),
   contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.description)
)
```

And create an util method:

```
@Composable
fun debugPlaceholder(@DrawableRes debugPreview: Int) =
    if (LocalInspectionMode.current) {
        painterResource(id = debugPreview)
    } else {
        null
    }
```

You can see more here: https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/

Comment: But this will also work in non-preview logic, isn't it? Maybe I don't want to show anything while the image is loading/in case of error in runtime - just something to see the actual bounds of image in layout while composing and looking at the preview...

Comment: Exactly, you are right. I just updated my answer with the code I'm using to solve completely this problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Coil, you can use the `previewPlaceholder` parameter, e.g.:

```
Image(
    painter = rememberCoilPainter(
        request = "https://picsum.photos/300/300",
        previewPlaceholder = R.drawable.placeholder,
    ),
    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.image_content_desc),
)
```

Source: https://google.github.io/accompanist/coil/#previews

Comment: Thanks, that works! Though I find myself obliged to put a placeholder image to my project. In xml, if was possible to use avatars embedded in Android Studio, like: `tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"`

Comment: This link is broken. Is there an equivalent?